importing external modules in virtual environment in Python is slow
I am testing using virtual environment in windows 11 with vscode.

I have created a virtual environment (called .venv).
I have activated the environment (.venv\Scripts\activate).
I then pip install various_modules
I then run some sample code (below).

import time
print('hello')

t0 = time.time()
print('doing import')
import requests
print('import done')
t1 = time.time()

print('time taken:', round(t1 - t0, 3), 'seconds.')

I note that the time taken for some modules to import is really long.

requests takes over 20 seconds
numpy take 7 seconds
pandas takes 5 seconds

whilst the builtin modules are much faster.

os takes 0.00 seconds
pprint takes 0.01 seconds

I further note that when i do not use the virtual environment everything runs as normal.
I have seen this post which is similar, but the accepted answer did not work:

Importing modules from a virtual environment in Python

so my question is this:

Why do the external modules take so long to load ?
what can i do to make external modules run with normal speed in a virtual environment ?

